# SQL Statement that excludes the same records in a relational database

Tags: sql, database, relational-database

I have this table relationship

[image: table relationship]

It's a job assignment database in which, as soon a job is assigned to an user, the `Jobs Management` table gets a new record with the corresponding data (the user ID assigned to and the job ID that was assigned).

I'd like to create an interface that helps the manager assign the jobs that aren't assigned yet. For that, which would be the SQL STATEMENT that select every job but excludes any job that is already assigned (it means that its ID is already in `Jobs Management` table)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to express this in SQL.  I think this is the most straightforward:

```
  SELECT ID, Nome FROM Jobs WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT Jobs_ID FROM JobsManagement)
```